# "IN" query in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

i'm trying to get this query :

```
$my_query = "select * from tableuser where `userid`<> '$userid' and userid in 
(select friend from userrelations where blocked='no' and user_id='$userid')";
```

to work in `Laravel 5.2`

what i tried so far :

```
$query_first = DB::table('userrelations')
                 ->select('friend')
                 ->where('blocked' , '=', 'no')
                 ->where('user_id' , '=', $userid)
                 ->get();

$my_query = DB::table('tableuser')
                 ->select('*')
                 ->where('userid' , '<>', $userid)
                 ->where('userid' , 'in', $query_first)
                 ->get();
```

by doing this i get empty result, which is not correct.

any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first query you should replace

```
->get();
```

with

```
->pluck('id');
```

With [pluck()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#retrieving-results) you'll get an array of ids instead of array of objects.

---

Then, incorrect part in second query:

> ->where('userid' , 'in', $query_first)

There's [`whereIn()`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#where-clauses):

```
$users = DB::table('tableuser')->whereIn('userid', $query_first)->get();
```